# How to find node that have minimum average distance to given nodes faster?

Tags: python, networkx

i'm try to find node that have most minimum distance to given node and this is what i have try.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_gpickle("Database/Pickle/test.gpickle")

targetcount = dict() #store number of reach to given node.
targetdistance = dict() #sum of distance to all of given node.

givennode = ['car', 'home', 'man']

#step1,find node that have path to givennode and store distance in dictionary 
#by using single_source_dijkstra_path_length()
for source in givennode:
    reachnode = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(G, source, weight='cost')

    #than store target node and distance from reachnode variable.
    for target in reachnode:
        if target in targetcount:
            targetcount[target] += 1
            targetdistance[target] += reachnode[target]
        else:
            targetcount[target] = 1
            targetdistance[target] = reachnode[target]

minaverage = 999999999.99
finalword = ''

#step2, find average distance only node that can reach to all of given word.
for target in targetcount:
    #if node have reach number equal to givennode amount.
    if targetcount[target] == len(givennode):
        averagedistance = targetdistance[target] / len(givennode)
        if averagedistance < minaverage:
            minaverage = averagedistance
            finalword = target

print("Min average distance word :"+finalword)
```

This code takes about 9 second by do these 2 steps.

step1 : find node that can reachable from given node and store distance to dictionary.

step2 : find most minimun average distance to given node by calculate only node that can have path to all given node.

So, are there any suggestion or other way to find minimum average distance of given node faster.

Thanks

Comment: one thing that caught my eye is that in step 1, your comment says you're intending to build a list of the nodes connected to `source` but you're actually calculating the shortest path lengths between the source and all connected nodes.

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley sorry I missed out, i mean find node that have path to source and store distance to dictionary.

Comment: oh ok. Calculating shortest path's just takes a while. You might try some of the other algorithms, A*, BellmanFord, Johnson's https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html

Comment: and if your network is not directed, make sure that you're only calculating each distance once, instead of the full square matrix of distances